# Multiple xampp installations for multiple php versions

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have configured two `Xampp` servers in different drives. I have `Xampp` for `php 7.4` and `php 8` in `C drive` and `D drive` respectively. Previously, before installation of the `xampp` in the `D drive`, I have configured `FastCGI` on xampp server, the one in `C drive`, for running project of `php 5.6` version. Hence I used to use `php 5.6` and `7.4` both on `C drive xampp server`.

The fact is, the `apache` and `mysql` `services` are registered in `WINDOWS 10 registry`, where the `ImagePath` for both services is set at

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
```

Whenever we `START` the `apache` and `mysql` services from `Xampp server` it checks for the respective `ImagePath` in the `Windows registry` to run both the `services`.

The issue is, After configuration of second `xampp` in `D drive`, I have to manually change the `ImagePath="C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice` of `Apache2.4` and `ImagePath=C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql` of `mysql` services which is getting a bit hectic as I have to run multiple projects of different PHP versions at the same time.

I need to know any way around for this if anyone has !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup i use for my preference and work is,

Xampp (latest) 8.2

Laragon(maintains multiple php versions)

On xampp i use database and on laragon i use php.

In this manner i get to run single database against any php version.

2nd i get multiple version of php on just a single click. Yes ot takes time to make this environment first but it's good. I have on my system 5.6, 7.0,7.2,7.3,7.4,8.0,8.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).